# How to modify json file section adding multiple links from a links gateway

Tags: python, json, visual-studio

I'm new to programming and i'm stuck on changing a big json file number +5k, this is my code :

```
{
"name": "#1",
"description": "#",
"image": "IPFS",
"attributes": [{
    "trait_type": "Name",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "trait_type": "breed",
    "value": "1"
}] }
```

so i want to change this section "IPFS" I mean substitute IPFS with 5k images links in all the 5k json files, i have the 5k image links gateway where images links are stored in order from 1 to 5k, so the operation will be like this :
1.json

```
{
"name": "#1",
"description": "#",
"image": "http://ipfs.com/1.png",
"attributes": [{
    "trait_type": "Name",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "trait_type": "breed",
    "value": "1"
}]}
```

2.json

```
{
"name": "#2",
"description": "#",
"image": "http://ipfs.com/2.png",
"attributes": [{
    "trait_type": "Name",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "trait_type": "breed",
    "value": "1"
}]}
```

and like this, until 5k JSON will be modified

- the image gateway represent one link that contains all the 5k images links.

Comment: So, what have you tried and what particular problem you cannot solve?

Comment: i tried a script based on BaseURI so the script change image links correctly but it change everything else in the json files according to a predefined information so i want to eliminate othe modification and change only image link

Comment: Please, read [ask] and then show your code - [mre]. Don't explain what you have done, show it.